# Is F/UTP cabling compatible with an STP patch panel?

Tags: layer1, cable, cabling, patch-panel

I've been given the job of wiring up a small office network, and been given F/UTP CAT6 cable to work with.

Is a patch panel describing itself as "STP" compatible with this cable?

As I understand it, STP means a braided shield around unshielded twisted pairs, and F/UTP has a solid shield around unshielded twisted pairs, so to my mind they can be patched on the same equipment.

The panel under consideration is a [Lindy 25882](http://www.lindy-international.com/0-5U-19-CAT6A-24-Port-RJ-45-Patch-Panel-Shielded.htm?websale8=ld0101.ld020102&pi=25882&ci=4003)

Thanks in advance. Apologies if this is not the best stack exchange forum - corrections gratefully received.

Comment: Make sure the patch panel is cat 6 or you will have impedance matching issues. Check the impedance specs and as Ricky mention all the specs. I can't see the shielding itself being an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they call "STP" is "Fully Shielded" -- a per pair shield and an outer sheath shield.

"Compatible" is open to debate.  If you want to maintain the panel *and* cable shielded specs, then no -- as the panel calls for shielded pairs.  But just the cable, maybe. You'd have to look at the specs for the cable as those tend to require bonding to a shielded crimp. (or a patch panel that shields each port.)